# How to prove that irreducible aperiodic finite markov chain's transition matrix can only have one eigenvalue of modulus 1

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

How to prove that irreducible aperiodic finite markov chain's transition matrix can only have one eigenvalue of **modulus 1**.

I know how to prove irreducible aperiodic finite markov chain's transition matrix can only have one eigenvalue of 1, given by the stationary probability distribution.

However, how to prove that there is no left eigenvector $u$ such that

$$u P = \alpha u$$
with P the transition matrix, $|\alpha| = 1$ and $\alpha \neq 1$.

My attempt:

$\alpha \neq 1$ and $|\alpha| = 1$

Case1: $\alpha$ is a $k$th root of unit for some integer $k$.

$\alpha^k = 1$, then $P^k$ has at least two different stationary states. It implies that $P$ has periodicity $> 1$, which is contradict to the assumption of aperiodic.

Case2: $\alpha^n = 1$ for some irrational number $n$.

However, I have no idea how to exclude this possibility.

Comment: The validity of the statement hinges on the chain being *aperiodic*.  Where did you apply the definition of aperiodicity in your attempt?  Also, can you prove the statement in the nice case where $P$ is a positive matrix (all components $\gt 0$)?

Comment: @user8675309 I used aperiodic in my first case. However I don't konw how to handle the 2nd case.

Comment: Your current approach is going to dead end with case 2 -- which is why I'm asking you to carefully state & apply the definition of (a)periodicity which I don't see.  (Btw, your statement "$a^n=1$ for some irrational number $n$" does not make sense when dealing with complex numbers; a better way to write it is $a^k\neq 1$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$.) You also didn't answer my question about positive matrices which is a very useful case to first consider (i.e. Perron theory as opposed to Perron-Frobenus theory). Note: an irreducible *periodic* finite state chain can also only have one Perron root.